# How to show that skeletons of equivalent categories are isomorphic

Tags: category-theory

Apparently, skeletons of two equivalent categories are equivalent but how to show that they are isomorphic?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Suppose $C$ and $D$ are skeletal categories and $F:C\to D$ is an equivalence.  Then $F$ is fully faithful and essentially surjective.  Since $D$ is skeletal, essentially surjective implies $F$ is surjective on objects, and then fullness implies $F$ is surjective on morphisms.  If $x,y\in C$ are two objects such that $F(x)=F(y)=z$ for some $z\in D$, then by fullness there are maps $f:x\to y$ and $g:y\to x$ which $F$ sends to the identity map $1_z:z\to z$.  But then $F(fg)=1_z=F(gf)$, so since $F$ is faithful $fg=1_y$ and $gf=1_x$, so $f$ and $g$ are inverse isomorphisms.  Since $C$ is skeletal, this implies $x=y$.

Thus $F$ is injective on objects.  Since $F$ is faithful, it follows that it is also injective on morphisms.  Thus $F$ is bijective on objects and morphisms, and is thus an isomorphism of categories.